# How to resolve a description ["detail": Unsupported media type "" in request.] when I hit API with PUT method?

Tags: django-rest-framework, swift5

I'm currently developing an application using SwiftUI.

I want to update some data in a database hitting an endpoint made by Django REST Framework from ios app.

When I try to update(`PUT method`) some data in the browseable page in Django REST Framework it works well and I can update the data, but when I try to do the same thing from the ios app, it doesn't work well...

And then I receive some messages in a console like below:

```
The response code is 415
The request is: ["detail": Unsupported media type "" in request.]
```

How could I resolve this problem?

---

Here is a code in SwiftUI:

```
 func makePutCall(
        pk the_pk:Int,
        field_name the_field_name:String,
        memo the_memo:String
    ) {
        let pk = the_pk
        let endpoint: String = "https://sample.com/api/info/\(pk)/"
        
        guard let url = URL(string: endpoint) else {
            print("Error: cannot create URL")
            return
        }
        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
        urlRequest.addValue("token xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", forHTTPHeaderField: "authorization")
        urlRequest.httpMethod = "PUT"
        urlRequest.httpBody = "field_name=\(the_field_name)&memo=\(the_memo)".data(using: .utf8)
        let session = URLSession.shared
        let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest) {
            (data, response, error) in
            guard error == nil else {
                print("error calling PUT")
                print(error!)
                return
            }
            guard let responseData = data else {
                print("Error: did not receive data")
                return
            }
            guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
                print("Error: did not response data")
                return
            }
            print("The response code is \(response.statusCode)")
            do {
                guard let receivedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData,
                                                                          options: []) as? [String: Any] else {
                    print("Could not get JSON from responseData as dictionary")
                    return
                }
                print("The request is: " + receivedData.description)
                
            } catch  {
                print("error parsing response from PUT")
                return
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

---

**UPDATED**:

I tried to add some code to set a `Content-Type` like below, then the error messages changed but I can't still update some data...

```
  ...
  var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
  urlRequest.addValue("token xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", forHTTPHeaderField: "authorization")
  urlRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type") //←I added this line
  urlRequest.httpMethod = "PUT"
  ...
```

Here are the massages:

```
The response code is 400
The request is: ["detail": JSON parse error - Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)]
```

---

Xcode:Version 12.0.1

DjangoRESTframework： 3.12.1

Django：3.1.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try outputting the value you're sending in the `PUT` request. Ensure it follows JSON format, and that there's no trailing comma in the JSON data.

Comment: I changed the HTTP body to array data and it works well then.

Answer (score 0):

The data you are sending is not properly formatted as json object which gives that err. Please try to find the syntax error in the data you are send in the request.